# is this structure is correct?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

"**Safer than with**" is correct?
I have seen some sentences using this structure, I think it should be safer that not safer than with, could you please help me in this issue?
For exp:  as it does not produce vapors and has a high flash point
transportation, handling and storage are **safer than with** diesel

Comment: Yes, "safer than with" is correct

Comment: Actually I never seen some structure like this before, could you please explain more about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the construction is this:

> It is X **with** Y **than with** Z.

Simply saying *it is safer than with diesel* is missing an important part of the comparison.

---

> As it does not produce vapors and has a high flash point transportation, handling and storage are safer than with diesel.

This sentence is ungrammatical. The problem lies in what follows the comma:

> (its) handling and storage are safer than with diesel

Even though the meaning is clear, the syntax is wrong.

---

A fuller sentence that would be grammatical is something like this:

> As *it* does not produce vapors and has a high flash point [during] transportation, **the** handling and storage **of** ***it*** **is** safer than **the handling and storage of** diesel.

Or, in a shorter form:

> As *it* does not produce vapors and has a high flash point [during] transportation, **the** handling and storage **of** ***it*** **is** safer than **that of** diesel.

Alternatively, the following is also possible:

> As *it* does not produce vapors and has a high flash point [during] transportation, ***its*** handling and storage **is** safer than **diesel's**.

---

Note that I used *handling and storage* ***of*** instead of *handling and storage* ***with***. This is because you're not using diesel as part of the handling and storage procedure—instead, it's what you actually *are* handling and storing.

To compare, look at this sentence:

> The handling and storage **of** it **with gloves** is safer **than** (its handling and storage) **without** gloves.

Or, in short:

> It is safer **with** gloves **than without** them.

This formulation could also express a comparison between to positive things:

> Steak is better **with** vegetables **than with** fruit.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine these two sentences:

"Because solid fuel does not produce vapours, handling and storage are safer than with diesel"

"Because solid fuel does not produce vapours, handling and storage are safer than diesel"

In the second sentence the comparison is ambiguous, and could be taken to be between two different things:

- "handling and storing solid fuel";
- "diesel".

In other words, we are assigning "diesel" with a "safety value", but this isn't what the intent of the sentence was.

In the first sentence we use the "with" to make the comparison explicitly between:

- "handling and storing solid fuel";
- "handling and storing diesel".

Another way to think of this, is what the "with diesel" means.  It could be expanded like this: "they are with diesel".  Which in turn could be expanded to this: "handling and storage are with diesel".